# How can I implement a tag engine in PHP?

Tags: php, tags

I've been trying to implement [PHP Tag Engine](http://phptagengine.com/) in my application but only succeeded to do it partially. According to the documentation, to call the HTML form to modify an existing item's tags you should use the following code:

```
$pte->html_item_tags($item_id)
```

The thing is that nothing is explained about how to call the tags form for a new item (one which doesn't have an ID yet).

Does anyone know how to do it?

Also, in **$pte->html_item_tags($item_id)** $item_id cannot be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.

On line 914 in file phptagengine.class.inc.php add:

```
if ($tags==false)
{
    $tags=array();
}
```

No you can call the HTML form with $pte->html_item_tags()

Don't know why the developer forgot this part.

Cheers,

Roy.